# Is there a way to force Assets to redo transforms?

Tags: image-transforms, assets, cache

Client has uploaded a number of severely badly lighted photographs for a 'staff' section of a site and these all have had a 'staffThumb' transform applied to it on the sites pages.

I corrected the lighting on the originals in Photoshop and re-uploaded those -- how do I make assets redo these transforms? Deleting the images in the _staffthumb folder doesn't do it.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't actually reproduce your problem but here's a couple of things to check and try:

1. Clear your browsers cache!
2. Did you re-upload through Assets with the same filename and click replace?
3. Purge all the caches via the Clear Caches button on the settings page
4. Update Asset Indexes on that same page
5. Failing those, manually delete the contents of the /craft/storage/runtime/assets and /craft/storage/runtime/cache folders
6. You can also try deleting the generated images manually in web/assets/..
7. If you're still weeping into your coffee try emptying the craft_assettransformindex table in the database

Of course, back everything up before you try all this...

Comment: option 3 did the trick thanks. Next time I'll try option 2 rather than going via an FTP app. Cheers!

Comment: No problem! I'd always advise using the Assets control panel - you can just batch upload a whole selection of images and Craft will just replace them whilst still keeping the links to the images in the entries. It will then also handle any cache purging that needs to happen :)

Comment: JoshAngell: batch upload through FTP or is there a batch uploader in Craft I haven't found?

Comment: @DavidRhoden I simply meant you can upload multiple files at once.

Comment: Thanks @Josh! My image transforms weren't showing up...seeing your answer, I cleared my caches and now they work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found that a really easy way to rebuild transitions is to simply change the transform settings in the craft admin interface. For example maybe your transform is to 400 pixels, change it to 200 pixels and the cms should regenerate the images for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured this out by now. But I go into my images folder and remove the sub-directories that Craft sets up for each transform. For example if you have a transform set up as thumbnail140 you should see a directory by the same name. Remove that directory and its contents to force a re-transformation.

Comment: why is this downvoted? this works for me as well.