# Efficiently writing multiple transforms

Tags: image-transforms, responsive-images

I use a responsive image plugin similar to picturefill.

On my local environement it works well, on my live install however the last trasnform isn't applied and I receive a 404. I guess it might be some memory_limit issue, so I wonder if there is a more efficent way to write this:

```
{% set fullw_trans_xs = { mode: 'crop', width: 767, } %}
{% set fullw_trans_sm = { mode: 'crop', width: 768, } %}
{% set fullw_trans_md = { mode: 'crop', width: 992, } %}
{% set fullw_trans_lg = { mode: 'crop', width: 1200, } %}
<img class="bttr img-responsive" alt="{{asset.title}}"
   data-bttrlazyloading-xs='{"src": "{{ asset.getUrl(fullw_trans_xs) }}", "width" : {{ asset.getWidth(fullw_trans_xs) }},  "height" : {{ asset.getHeight(fullw_trans_xs) }}}'
   data-bttrlazyloading-sm='{"src": "{{ asset.getUrl(fullw_trans_sm) }}", "width" : {{ asset.getWidth(fullw_trans_sm) }},  "height" : {{ asset.getHeight(fullw_trans_sm) }}}'
   data-bttrlazyloading-md='{"src": "{{ asset.getUrl(fullw_trans_md) }}", "width" : {{ asset.getWidth(fullw_trans_md) }},  "height" : {{ asset.getHeight(fullw_trans_md) }}}'
   data-bttrlazyloading-lg='{"src": "{{ asset.getUrl(fullw_trans_lg) }}", "width" : {{ asset.getWidth(fullw_trans_lg) }},  "height" : {{ asset.getHeight(fullw_trans_lg) }}}'
            />
```

I saw the answer of Brandon Kelly about [retina images](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/how-can-i-automatically-generate-responsive-images-from-a-single-hi-res-asset/1724#1724) with that macro thing but frankly, I don't get it. Could that be applied in some way to solve this problem as well?

Comment: Macros wouldn't help, they only enable you to write the code more DRY. But in the end, it'd trigger the same asset transforms as you have right now.

Comment: What carlcs said. Also, did you make sure you had  'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true, in your general.php file ? That's the best practice when using things like picturefill as it forces Craft to generate all transforms whatever the displayed images ends up being.

Comment: You can verify if it's a memory_limit issue by looking in your craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log file.

Comment: I added `'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,` and checked for phperrors.log but they are empty. The ima of `fullw_trans_lg` are still not generated. Any other way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue.

It was the caching. I cleared the cache in the cp and emptied the `craft_assettransformindex` table

I deploied the site to my live server but had the image folder on svnIgnore, so craft tought the images would still be there and didn't try to recreate them.

This [answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/117/is-there-a-way-to-force-assets-to-redo-transforms) helps.