# Is it possible to clear caches and re-index assets programattically?

Tags: assets, cache, image-transforms, deployment

When migrating a Craft site, I'm used to...

1. deploying files
2. checking my config, tweaking as necessary
3. loading a database backup
4. running "Update Asset Indexes" and "Clear Caches" from the control panel

That last step is always important because random oddities and broken images are fixed site-wide because of caching and transforms. Now I'm attempting to automate the process with a Docker deploy script, so I'm wondering: **is there any way to Update Asset Indexes and Clear Caches programmatically?**

I know that you can nuke the `craft_assettransformindex` table and delete the contents of `/craft/storage/runtime/assets` and `/craft/storage/runtime/cache` ([related question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/117/is-there-a-way-to-force-assets-to-redo-transforms/119#119)), but is that really doing the exact same thing?

*Note that by "programmatically," I generally mean anything you could achieve from a Linux terminal: MySQL commands, PHP or shell scripts, etc.*

Comment: Which caches, specifically, do you want to clear?  The clear caches tool has options for the various different places caching is occurring in Craft.

Comment: @BradBell Amended answer: ideally **all** caches, but realistically only those that'd be kept in MySQL since the filesystem would be squeaky clean on deploy—no physical transforms present and no additions to /craft/storage/runtime/assets.

Comment: I'm going with Fred's answer, then. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it depends. So, behind the scenes, Craft can have different cache drivers. You might use the db or file cache, or something like Redis or Memcache.

Took a peek at ClearCachesTool, and it looks like it's doing the things you mentioned:

```
craft()->db->createCommand()->truncateTable('assettransformindex');
craft()->db->createCommand()->truncateTable('assetindexdata');
```

As well as deleting all the internal cache folders (runtime/cache, assets, compiled_templates, temp), including any plugin cache paths that have registered via **registerCachePaths**.

```
craft()->db->createCommand()->delete(static::$_templateCachesTable);
```

It also deletes the templates cache.

I guess what you're looking for are these:

- CacheService->flush()
- ClearCachesTool->performAction() (does most of the clearing)
- craft()->templateCache->deleteAllCaches(); (called in ClearCachesTool - TemplateCacheService)

So yes, you can either bootstrap Craft and call a php file from the commandline, or add a plugin with an action that you GET/POST to after deployment.

The former, you can do with the included bootstrap.php file (as of 2.2)

```
$craft = require 'craft/app/bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the great answer Fred!

Answer (score 3):

### Updated

Craft version 3+ now has console commands built in that can handle these tasks.

```
$ php craft clear-caches/all
$ php craft index-assets/all
```

See documentation for [Console Commands in 3.x](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html) or [Console Commands in 4.x](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html)

### Craft v2

Take a look at [Craft CLI](https://github.com/rsanchez/craft-cli). It's a command line interface for Craft.

It let's you run commands like `craft clear:cache` and `craft update:assetsindexes` from the command line.